# How can I apply a function to modify column values? (Pyspark 2.4.5 - Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[image]

My goal is map each range and map it to its mid section (15000-25000 -> 20000).

I cleaned up the data and boiled it down to this column.
How can I apply the wanted transformation on the column itself\map the result to another column?
I cant find any understandable data anywhere on the internet regarding pyspark..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spark higher order functions `aggregate` from **`spark-2.4`**

Example:

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('15000-25000',)],['jobsalary'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("mid",expr('cast(aggregate(cast(split(jobsalary,"-") as array<int>),0,(acc,x) -> acc+x)/size(cast(split(jobsalary,"-") as array<int>)) as int)')).show()
#+-----------+-------+
#|  jobsalary|  mid  |
#+-----------+-------+
#|15000-25000|  20000|
#+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For spark<2.4

```
df.withColumn('id',monotonically_increasing_id()).\
   withColumn('val',explode('jobsalary')).\
   groupBy('id').agg(avg('val').alias('mid')).\
   drop('id').show()

#+-----------+-------+
#|  jobsalary|  mid  |
#+-----------+-------+
#|15000-25000|  20000|
#+-----------+-------+
```